# I want to produce report with ireport and i want to use my array in java as data source

Tags: java

```
package Metier;

import java.sql.*;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import java.text.NumberFormat;
import java.util.*;
import DAO.*;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperExportManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperReport;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JasperDesign;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.xml.JRXmlLoader;
public class MetierImpl implements IMetier {
    @Override
    public List consulterBalancee(int an) {
        ArrayList<PosteCompte> pcp=new ArrayList<>();
        Connection conn=SingletonConnection.getConnection();
        String numCompte=null;
        try {
            PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement
                    ("SELECT * FROM POSTE_COMPTE where UTILISABLE=1 ");
            ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
            PosteCompte pc;
            while (rs.next()) {
                pc=new PosteCompte();
                pc.setPosteComp(rs.getString("POSTE_COMP"));
                pc.setIntitullePosteComp(rs.getString("INTITULLE_POSTE_COM"));
                numCompte=rs.getString("POSTE_COMP");
                PreparedStatement ps1 = conn.prepareStatement
                        (" SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OPERATION IN ('Versement')  THEN MONTANT_OP ELSE 0 END) AS mouvDebit,  "
                                + "SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OPERATION IN ('Retrait')  THEN MONTANT_OP ELSE 0 END) AS mouvCredit, "
                                + "NUM_COMP FROM OPERATION WHERE NUM_COMP like '"+"%"+numCompte+"%"+"'AND YEAR(DATE_OP)=? group by NUM_COMP");
                ps1.setInt(1, an);
                
                ResultSet rs1 = ps1.executeQuery();
                if (rs1.next() == true  ) {
                    Operations op = new Operations();
                    
                    op.setNumComp(rs1.getString("NUM_COMP"));
                    
                    
                    int mouved = rs1.getInt("mouvDebit");
                    int mouvec = rs1.getInt("mouvCredit");
                    
                    op.setMontantOp(mouved);
                    
                    if(mouvec>=0)
                        op.setMontant(mouvec);
                    else
                        op.setMontant(-mouvec);
                    
                    pc.setOperation(op);
                    
                    int  ann =  an-1;
                    PreparedStatement ps2 = conn.prepareStatement
                            (" SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OPERATION IN ('Versement') THEN MONTANT_OP ELSE 0 END) AS soldeDebit,  "
                                    + "SUM(CASE WHEN TYPE_OPERATION IN ('Retrait') THEN MONTANT_OP ELSE 0 END) AS soldeCredit, "
                                    + "NUM_COMP FROM OPERATION WHERE NUM_COMP like '"+"%"+numCompte+"%"+"'AND YEAR(DATE_OP)=? group by NUM_COMP");
                    ps2.setInt(1, ann);
                    ResultSet rs2 = ps2.executeQuery();
                    if (rs2.next()) {
                        Operations so=new Operations();
                        int solded = rs2.getInt("soldeDebit");
                        int soldec = rs2.getInt("soldeCredit");
                        so.setEntre(solded);
                        if(soldec>=0)
                            so.setSortie(soldec);
                        
                        else
                            so.setSortie(-soldec);
                        int solde = ((rs2.getInt("soldeDebit")+rs2.getInt("soldeCredit"))+
                        (rs1.getInt("mouvDebit")+rs1.getInt("mouvCredit"))); 
                        so.setSolde(solde);
                         
                        pc.setOperation(so);
                        
                    }
                    
                    pcp.add(pc);
                    
                }
}
        
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return pcp;
    }



    @Override
    public List consulterAnnee() {
        List annees = new ArrayList<Annee>();
        Connection conn=SingletonConnection.getConnection();
        Annee ex = null;
        PreparedStatement ps;
        try {
            ps = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT year(date_op) as year  FROM OPERATION GROUP BY year order by year");
            ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                ex=new Annee();
                ex.setAnnee(rs.getInt("year"));
                annees.add(ex);
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return annees;
        
        
    }

    @Override
    public void rapport(List<PosteCompte> poste_compte) {
        
        
        NumberFormat formatter = null;
            formatter=java.text.NumberFormat.getInstance(java.util.Locale.FRENCH); 
      
            //POUR AJOUTER LES SEPARATEUR ENTRE LES MILIERS
            formatter = new DecimalFormat("##,###.## ");
            int a = 1;
        
        for (PosteCompte pcp: poste_compte) {
            
            
            String fileNameJrxml = "C:/Users/Bertrand/Documents/Impession/caisse2.jrxml";
            String fileNamePdf = "E:/Jasper/Blank_A4_Paramv2.pdf";
            if ( pcp.getOperation().getSolde()>=0 ) {
                
                
         
                try {
                        
                    String num = String.valueOf(a++) ;
                    
                    String compte = pcp.getPosteComp();
                    
                    String intitule = pcp.getIntitullePosteComp();
                    
                    String sod = String.valueOf( formatter.format(pcp.getOperation().getEntre())) ;
                    
                    String soc = String.valueOf(formatter.format(pcp.getOperation().getSortie()));
                    
                    String md = String.valueOf(formatter.format(pcp.getOperation().getMontantOp()));
                    
                    String mc = String.valueOf(formatter.format( pcp.getOperation().getMontant()));
                    
                    String scd = String.valueOf(formatter.format( pcp.getOperation().getSolde()));
                    
                    String scc = String.valueOf(0);
                    
                    
                    
                    System.out.println("Loading the .JRMXML file ....");
                    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fileNameJrxml);
                    System.out.println("Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....");
                    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
                    
                    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
                    hm.put("num", num);
                    hm.put("compte", compte);
                    hm.put("intitule", intitule);
                    hm.put("sod", sod);
                    hm.put("soc", soc);
                    hm.put("md", md);
                    hm.put("mc", mc);
                    hm.put("scd", scd);
                    hm.put("scc", scc);
                    System.out.println("filling parameters to .JASPER file....");
                    JasperPrint jprint = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hm, new JREmptyDataSource());
                    System.out.println("exporting the JASPER file to PDF file....");
                    //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, fileNamePdf);
                    System.out.println("Successfully completed the export");
                
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Exception:" + e);
                }
                        
                
            }else { 
                try {
                    String num = String.valueOf(a++) ;
                    
                    String compte = pcp.getPosteComp();
                    
                    String intitule = pcp.getIntitullePosteComp();
                    
                    String sod = String.valueOf( formatter.format(pcp.getOperation().getEntre())) ;
                    
                    String soc = String.valueOf(formatter.format(pcp.getOperation().getSortie()));
                    
                    String md = String.valueOf(formatter.format(pcp.getOperation().getMontantOp()));
                    
                    String mc = String.valueOf(formatter.format( pcp.getOperation().getMontant()));
                    
                    String scd = String.valueOf(0);
                    
                    String scc = String.valueOf(formatter.format( -pcp.getOperation().getSolde()));
                        
                    

                    
                    
                    System.out.println("Loading the .JRMXML file ....");
                    JasperDesign jasperDesign = JRXmlLoader.load(fileNameJrxml);
                    System.out.println("Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....");
                    JasperReport jasperReport = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(jasperDesign);
                    
                    HashMap hm = new HashMap();
                    hm.put("num", num);
                    hm.put("compte", compte);
                    hm.put("intitule", intitule);
                    hm.put("sod", sod);
                    hm.put("soc", soc);
                    hm.put("md", md);
                    hm.put("mc", mc);
                    hm.put("scd", scd);
                    hm.put("scc", scc);
                    System.out.println("filling parameters to .JASPER file....");
                    JasperPrint jprint = (JasperPrint) JasperFillManager.fillReport(jasperReport, hm, new JREmptyDataSource());
                    System.out.println("exporting the JASPER file to PDF file....");
                    //JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfFile(jprint, fileNamePdf);
                    System.out.println("Successfully completed the export");
                    
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    System.out.print("Exception:" + e);
                }
            }
            
        }   
        
        
        
    }   
}
```

This is the part where I created my functions to do the research and produce the report with the file caisse2.jrxml

```
package Utilisateur;

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.text.MessageFormat;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

import DAO.Annee;

import Metier.MetierImpl;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperPrint;
import net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRTableModelDataSource;
import net.sf.jasperreports.view.JasperViewer;

public class Balance extends JFrame {
    private JLabel jLabelAN = new JLabel("Entrer l'année");
    private JComboBox jAnnee = new JComboBox();
    private JButton jButtonChercher = new JButton("Chercher");
    private JButton jButtonImprimer = new JButton("Imprimer");
    private JTable jTable = new JTable();
    private UtModel jTabModel;

    public Balance() {

        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        MetierImpl metier = new MetierImpl();

        List<Annee> ex = metier.consulterAnnee();
        for (Annee a : ex) {
            this.jAnnee.addItem(a.getAnnee());
        }
        // List anns = metier.consulterAnnee();
        // Annee anne = new Annee();

        JPanel jPanelN = new JPanel();
        jPanelN.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jPanelN.add(jLabelAN);
        jPanelN.add(jAnnee);
        jPanelN.add(jButtonChercher);
        jPanelN.add(jButtonImprimer);
        add(jPanelN, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        JPanel jPanelC = new JPanel();
        jTabModel = new UtModel();
        jTable = new JTable(jTabModel);
        JScrollPane jScrollPane = new JScrollPane(jTable);
        jPanelC.setLayout(new GridLayout());
        jPanelC.add(jScrollPane);
        this.add(jPanelC, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.setSize(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
        this.setVisible(true);
        
        
        jButtonChercher.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                int an = (int) jAnnee.getSelectedItem();
                List clients = metier.consulterBalancee(an);
                jTabModel.setData(clients);

            }
        });

        jButtonImprimer.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            
              @Override public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
              
                    int an = (int) jAnnee.getSelectedItem();
                    List clients = metier.consulterBalancee(an);
                 
                    metier.rapport(clients);
                  
                  
              }
             
        });
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Balance();
    }
}
```

This is the part where I called the functions I created

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="caisse2" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="5e28c070-ccec-4436-853e-6a0ac5c8df1b">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <style name="table">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="1.0" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0F8FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_CH" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#BFE1FF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <style name="table 1_TD" mode="Opaque" backcolor="#FFFFFF">
        <box>
            <pen lineWidth="0.5" lineColor="#000000"/>
        </box>
    </style>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 1" uuid="cda93705-6dd8-4e63-8f7f-8fb64082e1c6"/>
    <subDataset name="Table Dataset 2" uuid="0987d8b3-73f0-4342-8a7e-695d59152e9d"/>
    <parameter name="num" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="compte" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="intitule" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="sod" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="soc" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="md" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="mc" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="scd" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="scc" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <background>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </background>
    <title>
        <band height="79" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle radius="10">
                <reportElement x="77" y="0" width="380" height="79" uuid="b87a1512-544c-4ca0-a980-321cd61638c0"/>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="156" y="10" width="222" height="54" uuid="d0523a6a-9317-43a0-aa84-7b9fef4af83e"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="24"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Balance Générale]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </title>
    <pageHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageHeader>
    <columnHeader>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="125" splitType="Stretch">
            <componentElement>
                <reportElement key="table 1" style="table 1" x="108" y="46" width="810" height="50" uuid="cf911d9d-939a-42bb-82fb-89d0b7b1566a"/>
                <jr:table xmlns:jr="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/components http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/components.xsd">
                    <datasetRun subDataset="Table Dataset 2" uuid="16f3e8b3-e3c9-415f-8076-4d8d1a43ecf0">
                        <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[new net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JREmptyDataSource(1)]]></dataSourceExpression>
                    </datasetRun>
                    <jr:column width="90" uuid="ed445967-c936-4a76-ba06-91fa37876937">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="30" uuid="58debb2a-6cab-4947-8317-caed865263a4"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[N°]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="90" height="20" uuid="9395357e-16f2-430b-93ef-cdbd02583eb7"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{num}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="103" uuid="12c88cea-f9d3-43a2-ab3a-03aa586c4c5c">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="103" height="30" uuid="bcff2f4d-85c3-4ccc-b9df-66e8640e9329"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Compte]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="103" height="20" uuid="6abfba7a-5501-4261-9b84-d92cfe51e53b"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{compte}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="335" uuid="504ba10a-f3d8-41a6-8ab3-6d074853d09d">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="335" height="30" uuid="5d258a39-b4d4-46d6-a254-515d4aa9fbbd"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Intitulé]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="335" height="20" uuid="049b1cbd-a6a6-49ab-a153-5cabf3ffad96"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{intitule}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="158" uuid="ec2036e2-b4d2-40b5-895c-19af07d7b66e">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="158" height="30" uuid="73cf4a6f-056f-43c2-86e3-2742c95d608a"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Solde Ouveture Débiteur]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="158" height="20" uuid="2fba3e31-bad8-4209-8f03-20197dddbb71"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{sod}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="155" uuid="289ec212-2b28-48c9-9a0b-1d52b0d4c590">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="155" height="30" uuid="d32ba806-fc0a-4888-a942-2b6f40314de8"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Solde Ouveture Créditeur]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="155" height="20" uuid="ffdda14a-2b02-4800-b949-ea53a951e063"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{soc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="144" uuid="3d6e08a8-e426-4981-b757-1d407ce0f940">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="144" height="30" uuid="f52e2a93-2a7e-449d-bbf9-546c9a1f5a68"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Mouvement Débiteur]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="144" height="20" uuid="bc599aab-12b7-48be-9fad-4145fcce62ef"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{md}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="130" uuid="7ccb60c7-5719-4900-a647-b1252d989d88">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="30" uuid="9a4c86de-a60c-4b04-a265-81984ece1dd9"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Mouvement Créditeur]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="130" height="20" uuid="9008fe73-21cb-4f09-90d5-31b6e7d25324"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{mc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="159" uuid="d95a47a7-6bcc-4595-8654-ee815e2526cb">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="159" height="30" uuid="5f491bd1-9b38-4643-9a08-a81081bae540"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Solde Cloture Débiteur]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="159" height="20" uuid="4cef04f5-6e42-407b-9a30-fec8f5d4e92e"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{scd}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                    <jr:column width="148" uuid="bc9e1c41-51cc-4aa3-adc9-2f97d682669b">
                        <jr:tableHeader style="table 1_TH" height="30" rowSpan="1">
                            <staticText>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="148" height="30" uuid="267f9ee3-23be-4c8f-914f-911f308b68f4"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <text><![CDATA[Solde Cloture Créditeur]]></text>
                            </staticText>
                        </jr:tableHeader>
                        <jr:detailCell style="table 1_TD" height="20" rowSpan="1">
                            <textField>
                                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="148" height="20" uuid="8fa5e518-c451-448a-995b-b3f5d9b2c6fc"/>
                                <textElement textAlignment="Center" verticalAlignment="Middle">
                                    <font fontName="Times New Roman" size="14"/>
                                </textElement>
                                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{scc}]]></textFieldExpression>
                            </textField>
                        </jr:detailCell>
                    </jr:column>
                </jr:table>
            </componentElement>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <columnFooter>
        <band splitType="Stretch"/>
    </columnFooter>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="54" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </pageFooter>
    <summary>
        <band height="42" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </summary>
</jasperReport>
```

Here is file caisse2.jrxml
In this file I created an array with 9 parameters. these are the parameters that I will put at the level of my java code to be able to produce the report

```
Loading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : sccLoading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : sccLoading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : sccLoading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : sccLoading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : sccLoading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : sccLoading the .JRMXML file ....
Compiling the .JRMXML file to .JASPER file....
Exception:net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRValidationException: Report design not valid : 
     1. Parameter not found : num
     2. Parameter not found : compte
     3. Parameter not found : intitule
     4. Parameter not found : sod
     5. Parameter not found : soc
     6. Parameter not found : md
     7. Parameter not found : mc
     8. Parameter not found : scd
     9. Parameter not found : scc
```

Here is the error I get. I can't solve the problem

Comment: welcome and please check [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [avoid asking question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: we use English on the site